# How return id in autocomplete instead of .country's name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I use Autocomplete from @Mui. I made this component

```
const Profile = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,

    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({});

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  const submit = async (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value.countries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("get-countries").then((data) => {
      setCountries(data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        {categories.countries && (
          <Autocomplete
            id="country-select-demo"
            options={categories.countries}
            autoHighlight
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.country}
            renderOption={(props, option) => (
              <Box
                component="li"
                sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
                {...props}
              >
                <img
                  loading="lazy"
                  width="20"
                  src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.symbol.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                  srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.symbol.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
                  alt=""
                />
                {option.country}
              </Box>
            )}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Country"
                inputProps={{
                  ...params.inputProps,
                  autoComplete: "country",
                }}
                {...register("country", {
                  required: true,
                })}
              />
            )}
            onChange={(e, value) => setValue("country", value?.id)}
          />
        )}

        <Button variant="contained" type="submit" sx={{ marginTop: 3 }}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Problem is that I need to return after submit in console.log id of country but it return country. Backend return json which looks like this: `{"id":1,"country":"United Kingdom","symbol":"uk"}`. You can see that I tryed using onChange in order to change defaul value but it doesn't work. **I can use hook useState but I use react-hooks-form są it doesn't matter**. I need to use register and return id from Autoselect.
How can I return id instead of country?

**@Edit**

I may not have explained everything thoroughly. I have a problem with the Autocomplete component. With normal select, I can add a custom value to each option, such as.

```
<select>
   <option value="1">United Kingdom</option> 
</select>
```

But I don't know is to do similarly in the case of this component

Comment: Wait I need clarifications, is this a backend issue? By your explanation I feel like you only need to return the `id` and not the rest? Or are you asking how to grab `id` from a JSON on the frontend? In latter case use `JSON.parse()` and access the `id` from the parsed data.

Comment: No, no. I have a problem with Autocomplete and I don't know how set id like a value of this select. In normaln <select>, I can set value for my all options but I don't know how do that in this element. I can't replace `{option.country}` to `{option.id}` becouse I want to see name of country into select.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekofeigen/autocomplete-react-form/commit/154a1b1946d0383c564c110263144abc7e22596e) displays a diff showing the only changes needed to get the code working. With these changes in place, the `console.log` output displays an object with the `id` property. The complete, updated version of the function is copied below.

A [live demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-76190240) (without the country flags) is available.

The problem was more related to **react-hook-form** than to MUI Autocomplete.

##### MUI Autocomplete getOptionLabel property

The MUI docs say this about **getOptionLabel**:

> Used to determine the string value for a given option. It's used to fill the input (and the list box options if renderOption is not provided).

The return values from **getOptionLabel** (a callback function) populate the *value* property of the native HTML `<input>` element. When a form is submitted **react-hook-form** reads data from the *value* property of the form's fields. In the code, **getOptionLabel** returns the *country name*, this is what is read (and returned upon form submission) by **react-hook-form**. This is the default behaviour when form fields are registered using the react-hook-form [register](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) function.

The important change needed to the code is to avoid registering the  element with react-hook-form. This allows us to avoid default behavior. Since, `id` is desired, not the *country name*, we need to use the react-hook-form [setValue](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue/) function to switch from using the default `<input>` *value* property to `id`.

The **react-hook-form** docs say:

> It's recommended to register the input's name before invoking setValue.

However:

> you can setValue to a unregistered input.

### Updated code

```
const Profile = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,

    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({});

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  const submit = async (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value.countries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("get-countries").then((data) => {
      setCountries(data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        {countries && (
          <Autocomplete
            id="country-select-demo"
            options={countries}
            autoHighlight
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.country}
            renderOption={(props, option) => (
              <Box
                component="li"
                sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
                {...props}
              >
                <img
                  loading="lazy"
                  width="20"
                  src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.symbol.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                  srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.symbol.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
                  alt=""
                />
                {option.country}
              </Box>
            )}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Country"
                inputProps={{
                  ...params.inputProps,
                  autoComplete: "country",
                }}
              />
            )}
            onChange={(e, value) => setValue("id", value?.id)}
          />
        )}

        <Button variant="contained" type="submit" sx={{ marginTop: 3 }}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I doesn't work. Value prop define default value of component. In this case default will be undefined becouse my value is json not id. But if I remove getOptionLabel it not display country's name/ For example - I can see list of country but after I choose the one it display [object] [object]

Comment: Hi @sadasdadssad. You are right about **getOptionLabel**. In your case it is needed. I updated my answer. In my demo, the country flag images cause errors because they can't be reached from that server. But, you can see the console.log output for the `id` after clicking Submit. Without registering the `<input>` field with react-hook-form you might have to find another way to do validation (if needed).